# How can I allow invited users to comment on cards in Trello but not add cards?

Tags: trello

I would like to use a Trello board to list support issues for my clients. I want to be able to post cards for them to comment on, but I do not want them to have the ability post cards themselves or move them between lists.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways you can do this, depending on whether or not you want to make the board public. Both make use of the comments setting found under the board profile.

If you make the board public, you can select "public" under comments in order to allow anyone with a Trello account to leave a comment.

If you don't want to make the board public, you can create a new organization for members of your team and members of your client's team and associate the board with that new organization. Then you can select "organization" under comments in order to allow anyone in the organization to leave a comment.

As a bonus, you can do the exact same thing with voting.

Comment: Shawn, thanks very much indeed for this. V helpful.